What is the importance of $SU(2)$ being the double cover of $SO(3)$?
To my understanding, it is important that $SU(2)$ is (isomorphic to) the universal cover of $SO(3)$. This is important because $SU(2)$ is then simply-connected and has a Lie algebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Now, $SU(2)$ also happens to be a double cover of $SO(3)$, but this seems coincidental/unimportant. It is precisely the universal cover properties which, together with some Lie theory and Bargmann's theorem, lead to a classification of the irreducible projective representations of $SO(3)$.
So, what is the physical importance of $SU(2)$ being the double cover of $SO(3)$? I prefer an answer in terms of the relevant mathematics as alluded to in the comments below this post.

As stated this is a question exclusively about math, so should be asked on that SE. Are you wondering about physical importance of the double cover?

People on this site commonly cite $SU(2)$ being the double cover of $SO(3)$ as a primary point of importance, especially in the context of talking about irreducible projective representations of $SO(3)$. I would like to understand what they mean. So, I think the answer is "yes" to your comment. @MariusLadegårdMeyer.

To add to my comment above, it seems like people often (perhaps wrongly) cite $SU(2)$ being the double cover of $SO(3)$ as being responsible for consequences that are really consequences of $SU(2)$ being the (isomorphic to) universal cover of $SO(3)$.

Sure, but it's still a maths question :) As an analogy, if people on this site discuss chemical bonds in relation to the physics of phases of matter, I might wonder about something since I have never studied chemistry. But posting a question purely about chemistry here would still be off-topic imho. Again, just want to clarify if you are interested in the physical or mathematical importance of the things you are asking about.

I see what you mean. I am interested in the physical importance, so I will clarify that in the post. But to also clarify, I would like an answer in terms of the relevant mathematics. I think to me the two are quite intertwined. For instance, a satisfactory answer to the question of "what are spin-$j$ systems" would involve talking about how to classify irreducible projective representations of $SO(3)$. Assuming one knows introductory quantum mechanics, the only physics there is defining the correspondence between physical and mathematical objects. @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Agreed! I don't doubt a good answer will be mostly mathematical ;)

Do you expect an answer to contain much more than « double covers are the easiest connected ones (because they minimize the cardinal of fibers) so we are lucky that some groups we study are as close as possible to be simply-connected »?

More on $SO(3)$ & $SU(2)$.

This could be of interest, especially my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808910/

It's actually Spin(n) which is the universal and double cover of SO(n) for n>=3.
However, it turns out that Spin(3) is isomorphic to SU(2). This is important because SU(2) is defined via complex 2 × 2 matrices. Thus we can use complex matrices to represent elements of Spin(3). This is how the Pauli matrices come into the picture.
